# unexpected indent python

Tags: python-3.x, api

estoy trabajando en python, algo nuevo para mi, se que este error es porque tiene espacios pero realmente no se como hacerlo trabajar

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import samsara
from samsara.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint

  with samsara.ApiClient() as api_client: <-- aqui es donde marca el error exactamente en el with
    api_instance = samsara.SamsaraApi(api_client)
    start_time = '2020-05-01T00:00:00Z' # str | fecha de inicio
    end_time = '2020-05-01T23:00:00Z' # str | fecha final
    vehicle_ids = ['490'] # list[str] | A filter on the data based on this comma-separated list of vehicle IDs. Example: `vehicleIds=1234,5678` (optional)

try:
    # Get historical vehicle locations
    api_response = api_instance.get_vehicle_locations_history(start_time, end_time, vehicle_ids=vehicle_ids)
    pprint(api_response)
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception when calling SamsaraApi->get_vehicle_locations_history: %s\n" % e)
```

Comment: Tienes la linea del `with` identada dos espacios de más, debe estar al mismo nivel que el `from`, quita esos dos espacios antes del `with`... Además, creo que el bloque del `try-except` debería estar también dentro del bloque `with`, es decir un nivel más de sangria.

Comment: Por cierto, la etiqueta marca python3, no necesitas `from __future__ import print_function` para nada (a no ser que requieras retrocompatibilidad, aunque Python 2 está en EOL), eso es para el extinto Python 2, para poder usar el builtin `print` de Python 3.